# "'\f', hexadecimal value 0x0C, is an invalid character" — Can't clean it

Tags: c#, xml, exception, ascii

I'm getting the dreaded "'\f', hexadecimal value 0x0C, is an invalid character" when attempting to save my Xdocument content to file.

I've Googled it and i've attempted to clean it by converting the Xdocument to string cleans it of non-ascii characters (see below). The method to do this I copied from another poster.

It's now throwing the exception where i try to pass the string to the cleaning method though. It doesn't seem to want to cast to string. I tried just outputting to a text fie so i could see what the problem character was, but it then threw the exception there. Any ideas please?

```
public void combineContentXmlWithS1000Dtemplate(XElement content)
{

    XDocument XDoc = XDocument.Load(GlobalVars.pathToDMshells + "\\descript.xml" );

    content.Descendants("para").Where(e => string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value)).Remove(); // remove all empty para elements

    XDoc.XPathSelectElement("/dmodule/content").Add(content); // adds the new tree to the S1000D template XML

    writeHeaderData(XDoc);

    //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(GlobalVars.pathToOutput + "\\Log.text", XDoc.ToString()); // It even threw exception here

    string cleanedXML = CleanInvalidXmlChars(XDoc.ToString()); // clean the doc of non ascii characters
    XDocument FinishedDM = XDocument.Parse(cleanedXML);

    saveMyS1000Dfile(FinishedDM);
}

public static string CleanInvalidXmlChars(string StrInput)
{
    //Returns same value if the value is empty.
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StrInput))
    {
        return StrInput;
    }
    // From xml spec valid chars:
    // #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]    
    // any Unicode character, excluding the surrogate blocks, FFFE, and FFFF.
    string RegularExp = @"[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\xD7FF\xE000-\xFFFD\x10000-x10FFFF]";
    return Regex.Replace(StrInput, RegularExp, String.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect the stripping of non-ascii characters to remove `\f`? A form feed is an ascii character...

Comment: Well i'm only going by what the exception is telling me. Do you have any suggestions as to how to help?

Comment: The only suggestion I can give is to maybe try to do a simple replace on the string to remove `\f`. If something like `myString = myString.Replace("\f","");` doesn't work, there may be a bigger issue.

Comment: `XDoc.ToString()` does exactly same as 'Save`, so if one throws an exception then both will. Provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: The fundamental problem is trying to represent some data in XML in a way that XML doesn't allow. Throwing out part of the data doesn't seem like a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this worked for me in the end:

```
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            object findText = "\f";
            object replaceText = "^p^p";
            currentDocument.Range().Find.Execute(ref findText,
                true, true, true, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref replaceText, Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Comment: What does Microsoft Word have to do with this?